# Closing completely an app not just an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to close an app with a button with this method:System.exit(0);
But I get back to the other activity ! How can I fix that ?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?  Do you have a service to stop?  You should not close an Android app without a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended, but this should completely kill off the app.

`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

To exit normally you should just invoke `Finish()` from your main activity.

Comment: Thanks but finish() just close one activity

Comment: @user2670035 you should use actionbar/navigationbar on click on home icon navigate to app home screen and click back button to exit the app. but you should not use `System.exit(0)`. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: You can pass or retrieve the context for your main activity and call it with that.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `System.exit(0)`. Use `finish()` instead .`finish` will pop the activity from the activity back stack and destroy it. Previous activity in the back stack takes focus.

Check this link and comments by Dianne Hackborn

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Zhd1fRfHAAQ

Check this link and comments by Romain Guy

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/G_D3pKnGLt0

Quoting from comment by Streets of Boston

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Y96KnN_6RqM

You should not call System.exit(). It could mess up Android's handling of the lifecycles of your activities and result in an awkward user-experience (e.g. when killing the process, the previous activity from which you laucnhed your activity may be gone as well. Android may try to restart the process again and re-create that accidentally killed
parent-activity. but still).

```
public static void exit (int code)

Added in API level 1
Causes the VM to stop running and the program to exit. If runFinalizersOnExit(boolean) has been previously invoked with a true argument, then all objects will be properly garbage-collected and finalized first.

Parameters
code    the return code.
```

[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

If you are looking for navigation use actionbar and navigation bar.

Comment: @ChrisThompson you are right. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/G_D3pKnGLt0